# include variable in ejs blocks :unexpected token error %

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I am trying to append a variable with `block` in ejs

this is my variable `<%=sails.config.items.base_url%>`

`<%block('searchScript','<script src='<%=sails.config.items.base_url%>'></script>')%>`

But i got the following error

`"stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token %= in \"/var/www/node/cushbuart/views/user/edit-art.ejs\"\n`

Comment: Try to replace `<%=sails.config.items.base_url%>` with `+ sails.config.items.base_url +`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%=sails.config.items.base_url%>

<%block('searchScript','<script src='+ sails.config.items.base_url +'></script>')%>
```

Comment: Let me try your answer